# Scipy.optimize with vectors and constraints

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, constraints

Thanks to everyone in advance for their time!

My issue is with  imposing the constraints for the optimization in vectors notation.
Basically I have already defined the objective function as:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize


def main():
    fake_x = np.random.random((60, 10))
    results = solution(fake_x, 0.05, 0.1)
    print(results)


def initial_weights(fund):
    index = np.asarray(fund)
    dim_index = index.shape[1]
    return np.array([1/dim_index]*dim_index)


def objective(w, fund):
    # calculate standard deviation vector and covariance matrix
    varcov = np.cov(fund, rowvar=False)
    # write down the objective function
    obj_fun = 0.5 * np.log(w @ varcov @ w.T)
    return obj_fun


def solution(x, lb_vol, ub_vol):
    varcov = np.cov(x, rowvar=False)
    w0 = initial_weights(x)
    cons = [{"type": "eq", "fun": lambda w: 1 - sum(w)},
            [{"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda w: w[i]} for i in range(x.shape[1])],
            {"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda w: w @ varcov @ w.T}]

    b1 = (0, None)
    b2 = [(0, None) for _ in range(x.shape[1])]
    b3 = (lb_vol, ub_vol)
    bnds = (b1, *b2, b3)
    res = minimize(objective, w0, bounds=bnds, args=x, constraints=cons)
    return res


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

The error I get is:

```
x = np.clip(x, new_bounds[0], new_bounds[1])
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 5, in clip
  File line 2103, in clip
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'clip', a_min, a_max, out=out, **kwargs)
  File line 58, in _wrapfunc
    return bound(*args, **kwds)
  File line 158, in _clip
    return _clip_dep_invoke_with_casting(
  File line 112, in _clip_dep_invoke_with_casting
    return ufunc(*args, out=out, **kwargs)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (12,) (12,)
```

If my understanding is correct I think the problem is that the size of the resulting array np.clip should be of the same size as w. I managed to apply only the non-negativity constraint by removing b1 and b3 as well as the first and last constraints from cons, but I don't understand how I can apply all of them together.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ok I edited the code so that you can just copy and paste

Answer (score 0):

A few basic errors:

1. `len(w0) = 10, len(bnds) = 12` This we can fix by:

   ```
    b2 = [(0, None) for _ in range(x.shape[1]-1)]
    b3 = (lb_vol, ub_vol)
    bnds = [*b2, b3]
   ```
2. I don't understand the purpose of `[{"type": "ineq", "fun": lambda w: w[i]} for i in range(x.shape[1])],`, so I dropped that. Singleton constraints should be specified in the bounds.

Now it gives some results.

Of course, you should not use a general purpose NLP solver to solve QPs. QPs should be solved with a QP solver.

Comment: 1) I followed your implementation but I’m not sure it worked the way it should. In that way the constraint b3 is applied to the last element of w. But instead what my intention is, is to have apply the b3 constraint to the volatility which should is represented by w@varcov@w.T.  2) The first constraint is to apply non-negativity to each single element of w. But maybe it’s the wrong approach.

Comment: If you want  `α ≤ x'Qx ≤ β` then you need to inequalities:  `α ≤ x'Qx` and `x'Qx ≤ β` (to be implemented as: `x'Qx-α ≥ 0`  and `β-x'Qx ≥ 0`. This introduces a non-convexity that can cause problems for this solver.  Typically we don't model these things this way. Consult the literature on portfolio optimization for what is normally done. If you really want this sandwich equation, use a proper global quadratic solver like Gurobi. Obviously, your constraints as implemented were wrong. You really should go slower on this. You can't be sloppy here.

Comment: Also, you are minimizing `x'Qx` (the `log` is rather useless) so these constraints on `xQx` are strange anyway. The covariance calculation is also suspect (normally on returns not on the weights). I suggest you discuss this with your teacher first. This approach does not seem to be very well thought-through.

Comment: I mean: the covariance matrix is usually computed once, outside the optimization. You repeat it again and again. This is not how things are done.

Comment: Well this is not the complete model I need to implement, so I imagine this is the reason it  looks sloppy, it was kind of a test to understand how I can apply constraints on the resulting portfolio variance which I still haven't find the solution. I'm not really sure if by wrong constraints you mean mathematically or coding wise. I posted the question specifically because I don't know how to implement the constraints in scipy. If you are actually interested in the model I'm trying to implement I can tell you the paper, I tried to reduce the problem to just this snippet code

Comment: Regarding the covariance matrix I totally agree it should be calculated just once, and as soon as I understand how to pass it as a constraint I will understand where exactly to put its calculation into the model